# Using Stack Overflow's visual style on other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, design

Would this be possible? It would help my poor eyes.

I guess there could be a Chrome/Firefox extension to do this.

Comment: Downvoters please add a comment so I know whats wrong with the question.

Comment: @Ismail Generally on meta a downvote means they disagree

Comment: @Michael , interesting but OK. Thanks :)

Comment: Which SE site are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do exactly what you asked for:

```
$("head link[rel=stylesheet]").attr("href",
                                    "/content/stackoverflow/all.css")
```

...but that also replaces the site's branding (= logo) with StackOverflow's. Given the site's markup that's not easily fixable (it'd require a StackAuth API call and the replacement of the `#hlogo a` rule, and then some hardcoding for sites the logos of which are designed for a black background).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you rather want to report an issue on the relevant site's meta, tagged "design". :)

Comment: Well, I could do that but I'd like to do that for _all_ Stackexchange sites, so I wondered if there is a common way of doing it :-) Thanks!