# Get rid of graphic backgrounds on SE sites

Tags: feature-request

Examples include programmers.stackexchange.com and apple.stackexchange.com

Why? While I'll be the first to admit that they sure are purdy, they're also pretty painful to browse over RDP sessions (which I occasionally do).

Watching the screen paint makes me think it's 1988 and I'm using pcAnywhere over a 14.4 connection.

Comment: This is not going to be a popular request, but it has a point - although arguably, this should be dealt with on the client's end. Isn't there a mobile version one might be able to use in such a case?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/using-stackoverflows-visual-style-in-other-stackexchange-sites

Comment: Before anybody else downvotes, I'd like to invite you to *try* it first so you can experience my pain. ;)

Comment: Sorry but I don't want the site to be text only like websites were back in 1990.

Comment: [Unix & Linux, too](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414/why-the-non-monochrome-background). [It's also a problem if you like a different background color](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527/background-image-should-not-assume-i-use-a-white-background).

Answer (score 7):

It's... a *public* site. If you're using RDP to circumvent localized blocking, you have bigger problems. If you're using RDP when you *could* just use a local browser... well, don't do that.

That said, try this: [MinimalOverflow - A themescript for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stackexchange) - it'll simplify the styles pretty drastically, and may help you out.

Answer (score 6):

Change your user agent to a mobile one like iPhone or Android, and you will get the low-bandwidth theme.

Comment: I'd love to try this. Is there a list somewhere of what "mobile user agents" are recognized as such?

Answer (score 1):

The range for network latency that creates your pain is going to be extremely large, as will be the differences in the display settings for mstsc.  I'm RDP'ed into the slowest PC I can find right now and the paint is just fine.  I expect this is not at all the norm for browsing the sites.  I don't see this as a broad enough issue to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Column 80](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu), it's a text-based read-only Stack Exchange browser that could save some bit on a 14.4 connection.

Comment: But I can't afford the 80 column text card! My Apple ][e only has 40 columns!